# External usb hard drive not recognized at UEFI boot menu

Tags: boot, uefi, external-hdd

I installed Lubuntu in an external hard drive, I had the bootable image in a usb and installed it on the removable hard drive, when the instalation finished and tried to boot to this hard drive it didn't appear listed, only my windows 10 disk appeared.

What can I do for the external hardrive to be recognized?

when accessing the external disk on windows this is what the disk contains:
[image]

uefi boot screen and external drive connected:
[image]

Any help aprreciated!

Comment: Is UEFI Secure Boot on? You may need it off. And/or do you have an UEFI setting for allow USB boot or full USB support. Booting USB drives is not considered secure, so  you have to specifically allow it with many systems. You should have a UEFI: flash drive entry. Is the install a USB live installer or a full Ubuntu install you created from a smaller flash drive installer? If full install, you have to manually partition in advance to have ESP on external device.

Comment: lso turn off ```fast-boot``` in Windows.

Comment: @oldfred it is a full ubuntu install I made from a smaller flash drive installer

Comment: Did you manually partition and include an ESP on flash drive? See this for several work arounds:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Old but still an issue with second drives. https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator/1056079#1056079